# Unit quaternions as rotations

Tags: abstract-algebra, rotations, quaternions

How would one represent the map $f$ such that $f(1) = i, f(i) = -1$ and keeping $j$ and $k$ fixed as a quaternion representation of rotations?

Comment: Rotations of *what*? *Which* representation? Please try to make your question as complete as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a small question of what rotation representation you're talking about, but I think I've covered all the bases.

The only representation that is going to be relevant is the representations rotations *of $\Bbb R^4$* represented as *pairs of unit quaternions*.

By solving the system of equations $q1s=i$, $qis=-1$, $qjs=j$ and $qks=k$, one arrives at the solution $q=\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4)$ and $s=\sin(\pi/4)+i\cos(\pi/4)$. Then the mapping $T(x)=qxs$ from $\Bbb H\to \Bbb H$ is modeling that particular rotation on $\Bbb R^4$.

---

If you're talking about letting a quaternions act as a rotation on $\Bbb R^4 $ via left multiplication (the left regular representation), then you are looking for the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, but that is not in the regular representation of $\Bbb H$.

If instead you are thinking of the usual representation of rotations of 3-space, one can't do such a thing: conjugating by unit quaternions maps the reals into the reals, so it can't map 1 to i.

Comment: How would you go about solving the above system of equations?

Comment: @BobHsu substitution should work. I took a shortcut when I recognized my system had turned into one describing a rotation.

Comment: okay, thank-you. one more thing, how did you find the matrix. In general, how would you arrive at a 4x4 matrix that rotates a specific set of axes in R4?
also, how exactly would you solve the equation with substitution. I'm having trouble seeing how to solve this sort of system.

Comment: @BobHsu It's just regular linear algebra using the basis $\{1,i,j,k\}$ :) This would be hard to answer in a comment, but it might already be answered, or you could post it as another question. It's very easy to show how to rotate a given plane and leave the rest of the space untouched. I'll work on the second half of your last comment in a new comment after this one.

Comment: @BobHsu Here's the method I used. It uses [this representation of 3-d quaternion rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternion_rotations). The first equation allows you to eliminate $q$ from the remaining three equations. From what is left, you can quickly find that $s^{-1}is=i$,$s^{-1}js=-k$ and $s^{-1}ks=j$. If you examine it, this is a rotation about $i$ of $\pi/2$ radians. The sine/cosine solution for $s$ is given by the link. Then I used $q=s^{-1}i$ to find $q$.